# Automatically pad SystemVerilog packed structs so that they can be put into a union

Tags: struct, system-verilog

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic vld;
  logic [`ADDR_RNG] addr;
  logic [`CMD_RNG] cmd;
  logic [`IDX_RNG] idx;
} pkt1Type_t;

typedef struct packed {
  logic vld;
  logic [`ADDR2_RNG] addr;
  logic [`CMD_RNG] cmd;
  logic [`IDX_RNG] idx;
} pkt2Type_t;

typedef struct packed {
  logic [???] padding;
  pkt1Type_t pkt;
} pkt1TypePadded_t;
typedef struct packed {
  logic [???] padding;
  pkt2Type_t pkt;
} pkt2TypePadded_t;

typedef union packed {
  pkt1TypePadded_t pkt1;
  pkt2TypePadded_t pkt2;
} pkt_t;
```

Where ADDR_RNG and ADDR2_RNG can be different.

As I understand it, SV structs for design (synthesizable) need to be of the same size. Is there a programmatic way to compute the size of pkt1Type_t and pkt2Type_t, find the larger of the 2 and then use it as the range literal in the [???] section above?

Or do I need to compute this manually or through the preprocessor `define?

Comment: if you know the largest struct, you can probably use $bits() , something like `logic [$bits(largest) - $bits(pkt1Type_t) - 1 : 0] padding;` But it would be better to use some parameter arithmetic to calculate you sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The dilemma here is only one union member needs to be padded to the size of the other member. But you cannot have a struct member with 0 width. So your packed union has to be at least 1-bit wider than the largest member

```
parameter MAXSIZE = ($bits(pkt1Type_t) > $bits(pkt2Type_t)) ? 
               $bits(pkt1Type_t) : $bits(pkt2Type_t);

typedef struct packed {
  logic [MAXSIZE-$bits(pkt1Type_t):0] padding;
  pkt1Type_t pkt;
} pkt1TypePadded_t;
typedef struct packed {
  logic [MAXSIZE-$bits(pkt2Type_t):0] padding;
  pkt2Type_t pkt;
} pkt2TypePadded_t;

typedef union packed {
  pkt1TypePadded_t pkt1;
  pkt2TypePadded_t pkt2;
} pkt_t;
```

There might be better approaches for what you are trying to do (i.e. tagged unions, `let` construct, but difficult to say without known more what you need to do with this.

Comment: Thanks. This is my attempt to use SV for design, which compared to SV for TB is rather limited. I'm combining two interfaces into 1 and sending the struct throughout the design rather than 2 individual sets of signals.